# How do you go back to the last evaluated expression in CIDER's nREPL in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, clojure, cider, nrepl

One thing I really love about using the Lein nREPL is that I can just go to the last evaluated Clojure expression by pressing the up-arrow key. Is there anyway to do something similar in the CIDER nREPL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the function `cider-repl-previous-input` which by default is bound to `M-p` or for `cider-repl-backward-input` which is bound to `C-p`. Look at their documentation to find out how they differ with regards to a search pattern.

And of course the corresponding `cider-repl-next-input` (`M-n`) and `cider-repl-forward-input` (`C-n`) are available to you, too.

Comment: Thank you! Here's the link to the relevant docs for any future readers: https://cider.readthedocs.io/en/latest/repl/history_browser/